# revolution slider height varies between domain.com and domain.com/index.php despite no variance in code

Tags: jquery, css, revolution-slider

I've got a third-party theme for a site that I'm building that is HTML5 and which uses a jQuery plugin called "revolution slider". I'm seeing a weird issue that I can't figure out after quite a bit of searching here and elsewhere.

When a visitor uses http://www.starcleaninggr.com/index.php the page loads correctly, with a max-height inline style value of 550px for the #revslider- element (note that the script randomly appends a two or three digit number to this id value but that doesn't correspond to any actual CSS rules; the css is all inline and generated by the script itself).

However, when a visitor uses http://www.starcleaninggr.com without the actual file name, the page loads with a max-height value of 230px instead.

There is no .htaccess file that changes anything and no .html version of the index file. I'm using PHP include() statements to include the header and main body of the page but nothing in the PHP sets or changes any CSS values.

What am I missing? I feel that it should be something obvious that I'm over-looking but I can't figure out why essentially the same page should cause a jQuery script to generate two different max-height values simply because one URL uses the file name and the other doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

The link: www.starcleaning.com is not working right now. It redirects to your hosting company straight.

I would recommend to set up the demo link correctly and contact ThemePunch directly via http://themepunch.com/support-center

Comment: We don't own starcleaning.com - that's someone else. The domain I'm referring to is starcleaninggr.com (it's based in Grand Rapids, MI, hence the "gr" at the end).

Comment: Sorry, my bad! 

You can set the first two wrapping slider containers to a min-height (e.g. 700px) like this:

`<div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;margin-top:25px;margin-bottom:60px;min-height: 700px;" class="forcefullwidth_wrapper_tp_banner"><div class="tp-banner-container" id="slider_home" style="left: -70px; position: absolute; width: 1280px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 700px;">`